# regexp extract groups who has initial and final token

Tags: regex

I want to extract groups from a String like this

```
hkjh kha 1112266 -stsi- XXXX XXX 6616 -stsf- aa bbb 17761 jjh1 jjh1j -stsi- YYYY -stsf- kjhjk  kkj jjlklkj jljkj -stsi- YYYY YYY 123 -stsf- jkhkjh shkahska
```

my regexp

```
(-stsi-.*-stsf-)
```

extracts one big group

```
-stsi- XXXX XXX 6616 -stsf- aa bbb 17761 jjh1 jjh1j -stsi- YYYY -stsf- kjhjk  kkj jjlklkj jljkj -stsi- YYYY YYY 123 -stsf-
```

and I want three groups like this

```
-stsi- XXXX XXX 6616 -stsf-
-stsi- YYYY -stsf-
-stsi- YYYY YYY 123 -stsi-
```

inside -stsi- and -stsi- can be anything

Comment: If the answer below does not work, please let know. Also, it would be great if you specified the language you are using the regex in with the relevant code.

Comment: What about `zzz -stsi- XXXX -stsi- XXX 6616 -stsf-` cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `?` quantifier after `.*` so that it will match as few times as possible (`.*?`):

```
(-stsi-.*?-stsf-)
```

In the expression `(-stsi-.*-stsf-)`, the character `*` is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), and it will match as many times as possible. The `?` quantifier makes it [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) and prevents that.